# Format of PHP Array to read from JQuery after Submit form

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need a PHP array that stores data from MySQL and later use in JQuery.
The sample data from MySQL table

```
student_id class_id score
001 01 A
001 02 B
002 02 A
```

In JQuery, I would like to access these data as data.student_id[i].class_id[i].score
How can I construct the PHP array?

My current codes in view_student.php (can choose more than one student_id, class_id)

```
$student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
$class_id= $_POST['class_id'];

$student_array = array();

for($j=0;$j<sizeof($student_id);$j++) {
    $query = "SELECT class_id, score FROM student";
    $query .= " WHERE student_id='".$student_id[$j]."'";

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($class_id);$i++){
        if($i==0) {
            $query .= " AND class_id=".$class_id[$i];
        } else {
            $query .= " OR class_id=".$class_id[$i];
        }
    }

    if($student_sql=$connection->query($query)){
        $student_php = array();
        $student_row_php = array();

        while($student_row_sql=$student_sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $student_row_php["student_id"]=$sale_row_sql['student_id'];
            $student_row_php["score"]=$sale_row_sql['score'];
            array_push($student_php, $student_row_php);
        }
    }

    $student_array[$student_id[$j]]=$student_php;   
}
echo json_encode($student_array);
```

In JavaScript, I need data.student_id[0].class_id[0].score instead of data.001[0].score

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault(); /

        var postForm = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({ 
            type        : 'POST', 
            url         : 'view_student.php', 
            data        : postForm, 
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType    : 'json',
            success     : function(data) {
                $('#score').html('<font color="#FFFFFF"> <strong>'+data.001[0].score+'</strong> </font>');

            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: `data.student_id[0].class_id[0].score` - this doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Why not `data[0].student_id`, `data[0].class_id`, `data[0].score`?

Comment: I really like your idea to access each attribute. But, I would like to know how can I access score of student for each class. If we use data[0].score, we can access only one score for each student. Please correct me, if I am wrong. Thank much @wavemode.

Comment: I think we can use data[student_id][class_id].score to access student score in each class. Thank you again @wavemode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this so that it resets the key indexing:

```
$student_array = array_values($student_array); // simple reindex
echo json_encode($student_array);
```

Since in the end they are already grouped by the students id, `$student_id[$j]` (contains `001, 002`, etc), reset your keys so that you can access them thru your numeric indices, instead of using `.001` which is the student id